# how to sort installed apps date wise in android

Tags: android

```
private List<App> loadInstalledApps(boolean includeSysApps) {
   PackageManager appInfo = getPackageManager();
   List<ApplicationInfo> listInfo = appInfo.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
   Collections.sort(listInfo, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(appInfo));

  List<App> data = new ArrayList<App>();
   for (int index = 0; index < listInfo.size(); index++) {
       try {

           ApplicationInfo content = listInfo.get(index);
           if ((content.flags != ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) && content.enabled) {
               if (content.icon != 0) {
                   App item = new App();

                   if(!item.isFavourite())
                   {
                   item.setTitle(getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(content).toString());
                   item.setPackageName(content.packageName);
                   item.setIcon(getPackageManager().getDrawable(content.packageName, content.icon, content));
                   long installed = appInfo.getPackageInfo(content.packageName, 0).firstInstallTime;
                   Date installedDate = new Date(installed);

                   // create a date time formatter
                   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                           "dd/MM/yyyy");
               String    firstInstallDate = formatter.format(installedDate);
              item.setSize(firstInstallDate);              
             data.add(item);
                   }
                   else if(item.isFavourite())
                   {
                       item.setTitle(getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(content).toString());
                       item.setPackageName(content.packageName);
                       item.setIcon(getPackageManager().getDrawable(content.packageName, content.icon, content));
                      data.add(item);

                   }
               }
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {

       }
   }
 return data;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a comparator below instead of `DisplayNameComparator`

```
public static class InstallTimeComparator implements Comparator<ApplicationInfo> {

    private final PackageManager mPackageManager;

    public InstallTimeComparator(PackageManager packageManager) {
        mPackageManager = packageManager;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(ApplicationInfo lhs, ApplicationInfo rhs) {
        try {
            long lhsInstallTime = mPackageManager.getPackageInfo(lhs.packageName, 0).firstInstallTime;
            long rhsInstallTime = mPackageManager.getPackageInfo(rhs.packageName, 0).firstInstallTime;
            if (lhsInstallTime < rhsInstallTime) {
                return -1;
            } else if (rhsInstallTime < lhsInstallTime) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The usage will be like:

```
Collections.sort(listInfo, new InstallTimeComparator(appInfo));
```

If you want to reverse order, do as follows:

```
Collections.sort(listInfo, Collections.reverseOrder(new InstallTimeComparator(appInfo)));
```

I haven't checked the code above, so it may contain some mistakes, but you'll get the idea.